# AngularJS - Initialize service without calling it

Tags: angularjs, service, dependency-injection

In my `AngularJS` application I want to initialize a factory service, without calling it from a controller or other service. How can this be done?

The reason is that I want the service to call one of its functions when the application loads.

Comment: You can always load the service and its methods using the app bootstrap function `run`.

Comment: I've updated my question, think I might have explained it the wrong way ;-)

Comment: As said by @AranS, you can call service method during run phase of angular module. We are doing same thing for our web analytics

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could just inject your service in the `angular.module(...).run(...)` function.
Then you could add the required code in the Service's main function/constructor.

But just injecting the Service without using it is a bad practice, because you or someone could remove it some day without knowing why it was injected.

So the best way to me is to inject the service in the `.run` function AND call a `yourService.init()` method that you will expose from your Service.
That would be more explicit.

```
app.run(['yourService', function(yourService) {
  yourService.init();
}]);
```